# Strange Xcode 14 issue

Tags: xcode

I simply created a command line C++ project, build it, and got tons of compiling errors

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ok, removed Xcode 14, installed Xcode 14.0.1, and the problem was resolved.
[image]